# Issues in Gensim WordRank Embeddings

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-embedding

I am using Gensim wrapper to obtain wordRank embeddings (I am following their [tutorial](https://github.com/parulsethi/gensim/blob/wordrank_wrapper/docs/notebooks/Wordrank_comparisons.ipynb) to do this) as follows.

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import Wordrank

model = Wordrank.train(wr_path = "models", corpus_file="proc_brown_corp.txt", 
out_name= "wr_model")

model.save("wordrank")
model.save_word2vec_format("wordrank_in_word2vec.vec")
```

However, I am getting the following error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. I am just wondering what I have made wrong as everything looks correct to me. Please help me.

Moreover, I want to know if the way I am saving the model is correct. I saw that Gensim offers the method `save_word2vec_format`. What is the advantage of using it without directly using the original wordRank model?

Comment: Where exactly does the FileNotFoundError occur? Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

So, I am gonna assume here that you got the traceback on

```
model = Wordrank.train(wr_path = "models", corpus_file="proc_brown_corp.txt", 
out_name= "wr_model")
```

See, the wr_path is supposed to point to where you have your wordrank installed, to be more specific, the path to the folder where your wordrank binary is saved.

So mine was `path_to_wordrank_binary ='/home/ubuntu/wordrank'` where wordrank is the folder that contains the wordrank.cpp

Then ensure that your corpus file is on the current directory. Since that's what you have given.

[This](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/master/docs/notebooks/WordRank_wrapper_quickstart.ipynb) is the tutorial you should be looking into.